# spring boot jpa storedProcedure issue with MS-SQL server

Tags: sql-server, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Im having some issues executing a stored procedure with a spring boot application and ms sl server db

it seems that the column names are being changed
he is the relevant code

```
@Entity
public class StationComplianceStatus {

    @Id
    @Column(name="nID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="strResult")
    private String result;

    @Column(name="strStationType")
    private String stationType;

    @Column(name="strActiveUser")
    private String activeUser;
//non ars constructor, getters setters
```

and the implementation is

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("my sp name as apprears in db", StationComplianceStatus.class);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.setParameter(1, "");
        query.setParameter(2, "");
        query.setParameter(3, "");
query.execute();
        log.debug(" after execution");
        List<StationComplianceStatus> stationsStatus = query.getResultList();
```

im getting this error

> engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
>   engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name str_active_user
>   is not valid.

Im noticing the column name was changed from strActiveUser to str_active_user, and I believe this is the source of the problem

Answer (score 1):

turns out the solution was simple as defining the following property

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy

ref: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2129